# extract multiple string from the command output

Tags: bash

In a bash script i'm trying to extract multiple parts of a string from output of command:
the output is :

```
mpaths (360060e80071df70000301df700000017) dm-41 HP,OPEN-V 
mpathes (360060e80071df70000301df7000000b0) dm-314 HP,OPEN-V
mpathdn (360060e80071df70000301df700000095) dm-243 HP,OPEN-V
```

My expected output should be the first field and last 4 char of second field (excluded the final parenthesis) and the rest   :

```
mpaths  0017 dm-41 HP,OPEN-V
mpathes 00b0 dm-314 HP,OPEN-V
mpathdn 0095 dm-243 HP,OPEN-V
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show relevant part of your code. See  also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for suggestion on how to ask good questions

Comment: The answer is clear and the rest of my code is not relevant. I will find the shell code for the problem. not else.

Answer (score 1):

I would use sed:

```
the_command | sed -r 's/\(.*(....)\)/\1/'
```

That discards the parenthesized word, except for the 4 characters before the close parenthesis.

If you need to stick to plain bash then

```
the_comand | while read -r a b c d; do echo "$a ${b:${#b}-5:4} $c $d"; done
# ..............................................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That underlined bit takes a substring of length 4, from $b, starting from position (length of $b - 5).

Comment: Or just `awk '{ $2 = substr($2, length($2)-4, 4) }1'`